# MySQL trigger: id of newly created row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to insert two rows in two tables in a MySQL database when a new row is added to a temporary table. (The table names are meant to be jokes here.)

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE atlas_id INT ;
    DECLARE atlas_city VARCHAR(20) ;
    DECLARE image_url VARCHAR(150) ;

    SET image_url := NEW.img_url ;

select member_id, city into  atlas_id, atlas_city from girl_members order by rand() limit 1 ;

INSERT INTO `ms_community_post_cpy`(`user_id`, `content`, `cover`, `type`, `is_open`, `top`, `order`, `status`, `add_time`, `title`, `good`, `is_check`, `tag_id`, `is_vip`, `is_recommend`, `click`, `city`, `search_num`)
VALUES (atlas_id, NEW.title, null, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '', floor(0+ RAND() * 10000), 1, 60, 0, 0, floor(0+ RAND() * 10000), atlas_city, 0) ;

INSERT INTO `ms_community_post_resources_cpy`(`post_id`, `resources_url`, `type`, `add_time`)
VALUES (NEW.id, image_url, 1, 0);

END
```

Here I need to insert the ID of the first inserted table namely `ms_community_post_cpy` into a field (`post_id`) of the other table (`ms_community_post_resources_cpy`) but I don't know how to get the value of the primary key of the newly inserted row in the first table. What is the right way to get one?

Comment: You aren't going to get answers until you improve your questions. how are we to know what the primary key is for the first table? Please add datable definitions for all the tables , the create trigger statement, sample inserts to girl members and expected outcome all as text.

Comment: Provide complete example: CREATE TABLE for both tables (skip excess columns), INSERT INTO with initial data (for saved columns, explicit values for autoincremented columns), the queries which inserts your data and desired data state after insertion and needed trigger working. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: *how to get the value of the primary key of the newly inserted row in the first table* LAST_INSERT_ID() function.

Comment: *when a new row is added to a temporary table* You cannot define a trigger on temporary table.

Comment: The other thing you could do is respond to comments and answers,

Answer (score 1):

A sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;
CREATE TABLE t2 (id2 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, id1 INT) AUTO_INCREMENT = 20;
CREATE TABLE t3 (id3 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AUTO_INCREMENT = 30;
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr 
AFTER INSERT ON t3
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (DEFAULT);
  INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (DEFAULT, LAST_INSERT_ID());
END
```

```
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT);
```

```
SELECT * FROM t3;
SELECT * FROM t1;
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

| id3 |
| --- |
| 30 |
| 31 |

| id1 |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 11 |

| id2 | id1 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 10 |
| 21 | 11 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0VQGLopy)